# Unity enum dropdown with float values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity / C#, is there a better way to do the following, currently involving and enum and a switch statement?

I want to be able to select the "Jump Distance" from a dropdown in the Unity inspector, but I want each of the values to be a float, not an int. Is there a better data structure or a different approach to achieve this?

```cs
    public enum JumpDistance
    {
        Short,
        Medium,
        Long
    }

    public class JumpTrigger : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private JumpDistance jumpDistance = JumpDistance.Short;
        private float jumpDistanceF;

        private void Awake()
        {
            switch (jumpDistance)
            {
                case JumpDistance.Short:
                    jumpDistanceF = 1;
                    break;
                case JumpDistance.Medium:
                    jumpDistanceF = 1.5f;
                    break;
                case JumpDistance.Long:
                    jumpDistanceF = 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            Debug.Log("I need to jump:" + jumpDistanceF);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Initialize a `ReadOnlyDictionary<JumpDistance, double>` somewhere in your code and use it wherever needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned use a map like e.g.

```
public static class JumpDistanceConverter
{
    public static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary<JumpDistance, float> JumpDistanceToFloat = new ReadOnlyDictionary<JumpDistance, float>(new Dictionary<JumpDistance, float>
    {
        {JumpDistance.Short, 1.0f},
        {JumpDistance.Medium, 1.5f},
        {JumpDistance.Long, 2.0f}
    });

    // And then an extension method makes actually sense without changing the values of the enum itself ;)
    public static float ToFloat(this enum jumpDistance)
    {
        return JumpDistanceToFloat[jumpDistance];
    }
}
```

and access it like

```
var jumpDistanceF = JumpDistanceConverter.JumpDistanceToFloat[jumpDistance];
```

or

```
var jumpDistanceF = jumpDistance.ToFloat();
```

Comment: Your code is a little rough (method has wrong return type, Dictionary on rhs of equals sign needs types), but its a good idea, thanks!

Comment: @Ben yeah typed that only on the phone, sorry ^^ Thanks for pointing it out, fixed it now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not elegantly, but here's a solution:

```
public enum JumpDistance
{
    Short = 100,
    Medium = 150,
    Long = 200
}

public class JumpTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private JumpDistance jumpDistance;
    private float jumpDistanceF;

    private void Awake()
    {
         jumpDistanceF = ((float)(int)jumpDistance) / 100f;

         Debug.Log("I need to jump:" + jumpDistanceF);
    }
}
```

... which makes it obvious. But due to implicit int-to-float promotion it can be further simplified to

```
jumpDistanceF = (int)jumpDistance / 100f;
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to think that your way is the good one, but you have to abstract that "switch" so it can be used everywhere.

So even if you use @MrUnbelievable92 way, which it works 100% but seems prone to someone making some mistake if they don't know how the values of the enum work, or any other way, you should abstract the method to deal with this, something like:

```
public enum JumpDistance
{
    Short,
    Medium,
    Long
}
public float GetJumpDistanceFloatValue(JumpDistance jumpDistance)
{
    switch (jumpDistance)
    {
        case JumpDistance.Short:
            return 1;            
        case JumpDistance.Medium:
            return 1.5f;
        case JumpDistance.Long:
            return 2;            
        default:
            Debug.Log("Error: this JumpDistance enum value is invalid");
            return 0;
    }
}
```

But if you like the way of @MrUnbelievable92 you can always do the follow to keep abstracting it a little bit:

```
public enum JumpDistance
{
    Short = 100,
    Medium = 150,
    Long = 200
}
public float GetJumpDistanceFloatValue(JumpDistance jumpDistance)
{
    return (int)jumpDistance / 100f;
}
```

In your final class, you will use it like this:

```
public class JumpTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{

    public enum JumpDistance
    {
        Short = 100,
        Medium = 150,
        Long = 200
    }
    public float GetJumpDistanceFloatValue(JumpDistance jumpDistance)
    {
        return (int)jumpDistance / 100f;
    }

    [SerializeField] private JumpDistance jumpDistance = JumpDistance.Short;

    private void Awake()
    {           
        Debug.Log("I need to jump:" + GetJumpDistanceFloatValue(jumpDistance));
    }
}
```

Having this clear, you can always play with static classes and extensions methods, achieving stuff like:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public enum JumpDistance
    {
        Short = 100,
        Medium = 150,
        Long = 200
    }
    public float GetJumpDistanceFloatValue(this JumpDistance jumpDistance)
    {
        return (int)jumpDistance / 100f;
    }    
}

public class JumpTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private JumpDistance jumpDistance = JumpDistance.Short;

    private void Awake()
    {        
        Debug.Log("I need to jump:" + jumpDistance.GetJumpDistanceFloatValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: I like refactoring the switch into its own method, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

@Lotan: Yes, you could get all sorts of crazy. The most unreadable version would probably be this:

```
public class JumpTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private JumpDistance jumpDistance;
    private float jumpDistanceF;


    private void Awake()
    {
        jumpDistanceF = jumpDistance.ToFloat();

        Debug.Log("I need to jump:" + jumpDistanceF);
    }
}

public enum JumpDistance
{
    // NOTE TO DEVELOPER : This will be divided by 100
    Short = 100,
    Medium = 150,
    Long = 200
}
    
static class JumpDistanceExtensions
{
    public const float JUMP_DISTANCE_FACTOR = 100f;
    
    public static float ToFloat(this JumpDistance jumpDistance)
    {
        return (int)jumpDistance / JUMP_DISTANCE_FACTOR;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, this is clever! Why didn't I think of that... Probably because it's just a little confusing. But definitely an idea!

Comment: Probably because extensions methods and enums seem like a very odd pair :/ :D